# Xamarin Datepicker: Is it possible to change the default DatePicker design and behave?

Tags: xamarin, datepicker, styling

The default Xamarin DatePicker looks like this :

[image]

How can I change his default style ? For example, I want to add multiple columns of months above the current month section. Also how can I make it to select a Range instead of only one date ?

If it is not possible to make those changes what you can recommend me as a more fancy Xamarin DatePicker choose (I also tried those from Telerik but I could find only the Spinner style Picker but I still prefer  calendar style ) ?

Comment: I think you can give a try to syncfusion calnder. They have a free licence version.

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-calendar

Comment: This is just a 30 days trial as I see

Comment: "The Community License is a complimentary licensing model that is reserved for organizations earning up to $1M in U.S. revenue, employing fewer than five developers."

Comment: https://www.syncfusion.com/sales/licensing

Comment: Also this looks more like a calendar without picker. As I saw the default DatePicker looks like spinner style... Can I at least do something like showing the calendar inside popup instead of that spinner ?

Comment: I think you can create something like spinner frame with arrow at end and on that tap open calendar control in Rg.Plugin.popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up by creating a new page with a calendar control (which allows me select a range and some customizations) instead of popup, so basically was not needed to buy another license from Syncfusion since I already have one from Telerik.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I do approve of the syncfusion datepicker but that doesn't answer your question. And the license is expensive.

I assume what you'll have to do is create your own new UserControl: "MyDatePicker" and let it inherit from the xamarin datepicker. There in the constructer you should be able to change what you want.

Be aware, the Xamarin components are still in an early "young" stage so you may not be able to change everything that you want.